# Why does my Gitlab Requests always return a Error 400

Tags: python, python-requests, gitlab

When I call the Gitlab API, searching for a User named Ed I get this Error.

I have tried curling the API outside of Python and I do not receive this error.

```py
import requests

r = requests.post("https://git.deploys.io/api/v4/users?username=Ed", headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN":"Removed Token"})
print(r)
```

It should return `[]` as if no user was found or it should return a JSON with the Users information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out what is returned: the [GitLab Users API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html) page does mention:

> If an error occurs a `400 Bad Request` is returned with a message explaining the error.

That, or it is a server-side issue, as in [`gitlab-com/support-forum` issue 2720](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/2720#note_48622945)

> The 400 errors were caused by a server side check that required a `User-Agent` header to be provided.
>   That's why only particular clients were affected.

Comment: Probably because it is another server side error. I have not seen any alert on GitLab side though.

Comment: is there anyway to resolve this anyway, on the client side or do i have to change something in the configuration settings on the server side?

Comment: @Edbtvplays an error 400 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) should be a client-side issue, but maybe checking the logs on the server side might yield some clues.